# Loading HTML files with dropdowns using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery .load to load different HTML files into my webpage using a dropdown menu. Each dropdown selection calls the corresponding file. My target div is `<div id="targetPane"></div>` to load the file. That works fine. I am looking to clean up the code so I dont have to write `$('#f1').click(function(){$('#targetPane').load( 'includes/inc_1.html' );});` 50 or so times.
The naming convention is that the #f1 will call inc_1.html, #f2 will call inc_2.html and so on. Maybe a solution using a for loop or `('option:selected',this)` ? Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#f1').click(function(){$('#targetPane').load( 'includes/inc_1.html' );});
        $('#f2').click(function(){$('#targetPane').load( 'includes/inc_2.html' );});
        ..
        ..
        ..
        $('#f50').click(function(){$('#targetPane').load( 'includes/inc_50.html' );});
   
    });
```

HTML

```
<form name="courseCalc">
            <select name="myCourses"
             OnChange="location.href=courseCalc.myCourses.options[selectedIndex].value">
                 <option selected>Please Select...</option>
                 <option id="f1" value="#">Item 1</option>
                 ...
                 <option id="f50" value="#">Item 1</option>

            </select>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that when working with `select` elements you are best off using the `change` event of the parent `select` element instead of listening for `click` on the `option`. It's better practice, more widely supported in various browsers, and follows accessibility guidelines.

With regard to your question, the technique you're looking for is called 'Don't Repeat Yourself', or DRY for short. To achieve it in this case you can hook the `change` event handler and use get a reference to the `select` from the Event object passed to the handler. You can amend the HTML to store the URL in the `value` attribute and then provide it as the argument to `load()`, like this:

```html
<form name="courseCalc">
  <select name="myCourses" id="courses">
    <option selected>Please Select...
      <option value="includes/inc_1.html">Item 1</option>
      <option value="includes/inc_2.html">Item 2</option>
      <!-- ... -->
      <option value="includes/inc_50.html">Item 50</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#courses').on('change', e => {
    $('#targetPane').load(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

Note that I added an `id` to the `select` element to make it easier to retrieve the element in the example, but any selector would work.

Comment: Fantastic. Worked great! Thanks Rory!

Comment: Quick follow up. As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68746908/jquery-load-how-to-target-the-loaded-file-with-javascript-and-jquery ... how would I add a callback function so that I can execute jQuery/JS in the parent template against the loaded HTML file e.g. inc_1.html? Thanks

Comment: Use the callback argument of `load()`. There's an example in the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/load