# DOM issues using jQuery .load() - how to load HTML file into main HTML template and execute jQuery/JS against loaded file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom

I am having trouble with an HTML file (inc_1.html) I'm loading into my main template (index.html) using jQuery .load(). My getTotal function doesn't execute the JS in Example #2 but it does execute in Example #1.
I was wondering if anyone could see what the problem is and whether callback functions (https://api.jquery.com/load/) or Cross Origin or DOM issues are the issue and suggest a solution?
Thanks and much appreciated!

*Example 1*
This method with all code on same page does work (not using jQuery .load() )
Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/hcanning2012/ftd8wspn/5/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        function getTotal() {
          var total = 0;
          $("input, select").each(function(i, el) {
            if ($(el).is("input:checked")) {
              $($(el).data("rel")).show();
              total += parseInt($(el).val());
            } else {
              $($(el).data("rel")).hide();
            }
            if ($(el).is("select")) {
              if ($(el).val() !== "0") {
                $($(el).data("rel")).html($(el).val()).show();
                total += parseInt($(el).val());
              }
            }
          });
          return total;
        }
        $('input[type="checkbox"], select').change(function() {
          $("#sum").text(getTotal());
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n1" value="200" data-rel="div.n1"> Show Price
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="n1 box">200</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n2" value="200" data-rel="div.n2"> Show Price
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="n2 box">200</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n3" value="200" data-rel="div.n3"> Show Price
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="n3 box">200</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
              <select id="n4" data-rel="div.n4">
                <option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="10">item 1</option>
                <option value="20">item 2</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="n4"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
              <select id="n5" data-rel="div.n5">
                <option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="3">item 1</option>
                <option value="4">item 2</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="n5"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Total: </td>
          <td>
            <div id="sum">0</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

*Example 2*
This does NOT work using jQuery .load() . inc_1.html loads in `<div id="targetPane"></div>` when selected in dropdown

```html
<<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.load Test</title> 
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/grid/">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            //open calc js
            $(function() {
            function getTotal() {
                var total = 0;
                $("input, select").each(function(i, el) {
                if ($(el).is("input:checked")) {
                    $($(el).data("rel")).show();
                    total += parseInt($(el).val());
                } else {
                    $($(el).data("rel")).hide();
                }
                if ($(el).is("select")) {
                    if ($(el).val() !== "0") {
                    $($(el).data("rel")).html($(el).val()).show();
                    total += parseInt($(el).val());
                    }
                }
                });
                return total;
            }
            $('input[type="checkbox"], select').change(function() {
                $("#sum").text(getTotal());
            });
        });
        //end calc js
        //open dropdown js
        jQuery($ => {
            $('#courses').on('change', e => {
                $('#targetPane').load(e.target.value);
            });  
        }); //close dropdown js
    </script>
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/grid/grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="py-4">
    <main>
      <div class="container">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                <select name="myCourses" id="courses" autocomplete="off">
                    <option value="" selected>Select</option>
                    <option value="includes/inc_1.html">Load inc_1.html</option>
                    <!-- assume more dropdown options -->
                </select>
                <!-- load include file here -->
                <div id="targetPane"></div>
                </div>  <!--close row-->      
        </div> <!-- close container -->
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Content of included file inc_1.html

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n1" value="200" data-rel="div.n1"> Show Price1
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n1 box">200</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n2" value="200" data-rel="div.n2"> Show Price
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n2 box">200</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n3" value="200" data-rel="div.n3"> Show Price
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n3 box">200</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="n4" data-rel="div.n4">
          <option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="10">item 1</option>
          <option value="20">item 2</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n4"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="n5" data-rel="div.n5">
          <option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="3">item 1</option>
          <option value="4">item 2</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n5"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Total: </td>
    <td>
      <div id='sum'>0</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Maybe the solution could be achieved using a callback function like:

```
                      jQuery($ => {
                            $('#courses').on('change', e => {
                                $('#targetPane').load(e.target.value);
                                path = (e.target.value);
                                //open callback function
                                   $('#targetPane').load('path', function(){
                                        
                                       //add solution here
                                       
                                   }); //close callback function
                            });  
                        }); //close jQuery
```

Comment: In example 2 the elements you try to select with `$('input[type="checkbox"], select')` are not in the DOM. They will be added when you select a course. You have to add the `select` handler after you've "added" `inc_1.html` to the DOM. See the dupe target for a _"How to"_

Comment: Thanks Andreas I will look into it.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I justs added the select handler before the closing body tag in index.html but form still does seem to execute the JS. Checkboxes don't toggle values or total values in the jQuery .load version (Example 2 above)

Comment: _"They will be added **when you select a course**"_. Adding the handler right before the `</body>` doesn't change the behavior of the script that adds the elements. Use event delegation -> the accepted answer.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll look into. JS ain't my forte to say the least.

Comment: Could you clarify "See the dupe target for a "How to" please? Thanks

Comment: Think I found the solution: `<h1 id="alternative">Go to the pub instead!"</h1>`